# Rest API: Register and Login errors aren't specific

Tags: rest-api

I've created a Register/Login form, and while it works perfectly for both, it's the error messages that are stumping me.

I've tried to produce the following errors for registering:

1. email already in use
2. username already in use
3. missing field

But no matter what I do the error I get is always 
`"Request failed with status code 400"`

This is the code I'm using to make the `post` request to create a user:

```
    const { username, password, email } = this.state;
    axios
      .post(`${Config.apiUrl}/wp/v2/users/register`, {
        username: username,
        password: password,
        email: email,
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      });
```

How do I get wordpress to spit out a more specific error?

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was having is that I wasn't receiving the full error object. To do that I changed the code to:

```
    const { username, password, email } = this.state;
    axios
      .post(`${Config.apiUrl}/wp/v2/users/register`, {
        username: username,
        password: password,
        email: email,
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log({err})
      });
```

Which then allowed me to figure out that the error message is contained in:
`err.response.data.message`

So now I'm all good.